# Write on a specific location in console with QT

Tags: qt, console

I am searching for a way to make my console output a bit more readable. I want to place some information in the console but with qDebug i cannot find a way to move the cursor or place a text on X/Y in the console.

I hope someone can help me.

I'm using QT 5.1 (cpp)

Comment: Maybe the console is not the solution you need... You're talking about graphical use and the console mode is not the best way to do it...

Comment: Well it is only for a few things and for debugging only. Just wondering if it is possible so i can use that without the need of a compleet graphical interface that i will never use again

Comment: Are you using Qt console or your system's console?

Comment: Im using the systems console, i cannot really find anything about Qt console

Comment: What kind of content do you display? Could you provide an example?

Comment: Line1: Temperature: 25
Line2: Current: 10A
Line3: Last fault: ....

Comment: You may be able to use escape sequences depending on what console/shell you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install your own MessageHandler:

### main.cpp

```
void messageOutput()
{
    QByteArray localMsg = msg.toLocal8Bit();
    switch (type) {
    case QtDebugMsg:
        fprintf(stderr, "%s \n", localMsg.constData());
        break;
    case QtWarningMsg:
        fprintf(stderr, "Warning: %s (%s:%u, %s)\n", localMsg.constData(), context.file, context.line, context.function);
        break;
    case QtCriticalMsg:
        fprintf(stderr, "Critical: %s (%s:%u, %s)\n", localMsg.constData(), context.file, context.line, context.function);
        break;
    case QtFatalMsg:
        fprintf(stderr, "Fatal: %s (%s:%u, %s)\n", localMsg.constData(), context.file, context.line, context.function);
        abort();
}


int main()
{
    qInstallMessageHandler(messageOutput);
    ...
}
```

And then format it the way you want, you can personalize the `fprint()` the way you want.